# Change macro to remove the unnecessary tail

Tags: c, boost, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I'm trying to write c89-compatible macro to translate sequences [ (a)(b)(c) ] to comma-separated parameters [ a, b, c ]. c89 means no **ARGV** and ... .

The code I have now:

```
#define SEQSPLIT(seq)  SEQSPLIT_SEQ(SEQSPLIT_I1 seq)

#define SEQSPLIT_SEQ(x) SEQSPLIT_SEQ_I((x))
#define SEQSPLIT_SEQ_I(x) x
#define SEQSPLIT_I1(seq) seq, SEQSPLIT_I2
#define SEQSPLIT_I2(seq) seq, SEQSPLIT_I1
```

with an input like `(1) (1) (1) (0) (1) (1) (1) (1)` I receive `(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, SEQSPLIT_I1)`. That's almost what I need, except for the last comma and "SEQSPLIT_I1".

How can I get rid of this "tail" without variadic macros and boost? (In the best case I want to remove the brackets too). Speaking of boost, they offer 256 lines of code for this like:

```
#define LOOOONGBOOSTMACRONAME_1(X) X, LOOOOOOONGBOOSTMACRONAME_0
#define LOOOONGBOOSTMACRONAME_2(X) X, LOOOOOOONGBOOSTMACRONAME_1
#define LOOOONGBOOSTMACRONAME_3(X) X, LOOOOOOONGBOOSTMACRONAME_2
...
```

After that they put it all to variadic macro.

Sure I can use the code the way it exists now, the last macro can be filtered by concrete wrapper like

```
#define WRAPPER_8(P7, P6, P5, P4, P3, P2, P1, P0, TAIL) \
                  P7, P6, P5, P4, P3, P2, P1, P0
```

But that means to end-user to write wrapper by himself. I don't want to left the tail in output at all (think about it like about replacing for boost with c89-compability and full 32bit arithmetic), because that tail means wrappers-writing for me too, since I can't use this macro directly in other functions that expect 8 parameters.

Comment: The C89 preprocessor just isn't made for such complicated ideas. Do you really have customers that: (1) want such a feature, (2) can't switch to modern, standard complying compiler?

Comment: I just trying to write the analogue of boost library and till now I had no problems with that. Mine main idea is to make it c89-compatible because I remember the task from my last job when we needed c-macro for firmware and that macro made unique number for interface-versioning. we only could use old Keil with c89 compiler. With boost or analogue I'd made it faster.

Comment: P.S. Of course I mean only preprocessor module of boost.

Comment: I think a better idea would to be to preprocess the code with a standard complying preprocessor. This is much easier to achieve, you can do this part cross-compiling on an other machine.

Comment: You can't preprocess the coe by gcc and then compile by Keil's compiler. Gcc has a lot of gcc-only stuff in its header files.

Comment: You'd have to adjust the include path, or alternatively find a way to just replace the preprocessor.